# select cell in pandas groupby object

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, group-by

I've got a pandas dataframe that I applied a weekly groupby function to. I'm trying to select the cell corresponding to row `2012, 12, 28` and column `ints` in the grouped dataframe `(grouped_df)`.

I use the line

```
grouped_df.ix[datetime.date(2012, 12, 28),'rate']
```

to select it, but it throws a `KeyError: (datetime.date(2012, 12, 28), 'rate')`. Is there a way to select this cell?

The original dataframe looks like:

```
            promoter  count    rate
date                               
2012-12-21        39     61  0.6393
2012-12-22        55     78  0.7051
2012-12-23        65     94  0.6915
2012-12-24        40     61  0.6557
2012-12-25        24     36  0.6667
```

And applying the weekly groupby:

```
            count      rate  promoter
2012-12-21     61  0.639300        39
2012-12-28    455  0.666471       304
2013-01-04    463  0.677214       314
2013-01-11    673  0.626543       423
2013-01-18    788  0.649200       50
```

grouped_df.info()

```
DatetimeIndex: 77 entries, 2012-12-21 00:00:00 to 2014-06-06 00:00:00
Freq: W-FRI
Data columns (total 3 columns):
count       77  non-null values
rate        77  non-null values
promoter    77  non-null values
dtypes: float64(3)Traceback (most recent call last):None
```

Comment: Can you show `grouped_df.info()`?

Comment: Your `grouped_df` seems to only hold one row with index 2012-12-21? So 2012-12-28 is not inclued?

Comment: BTW, what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: @joris, I updated the grouped_df.info(). SOmethign was weird. Should be correct now.

Comment: What version of pandas do you use? Because this works for me.

Comment: I think I got it to work. It was a stupid mistake on my part. Whatever caused me to write out the groupdf_info() that first way was causing the line to fail as well

Comment: Aha, glad you found the issue!